# Update bio in app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It'd be a nice touch to be able to edit your profile via the app. It seems it's not possible either through the mobile site (using Safari on my iPhone) as I'd like to be able to update my bio while I'm currently away from my Mac.

Comment: How often do you want to change your profile? Sure it can't wait until you are on a desktop / tablet?

Comment: You can click the "full site" link in the footer when using a browser, on mobile, then you can edit. Not really comfortable, but possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not so great on an iPhone screen. Most apps that have a social functionality allow you to edit your profile in the app, just seems like an obvious feature to include but I agree that it's not essential.